# Regex expression for decimal number

Tags: regex

Could somebody help me with regex? Basically, I would like a regex which matches with decimal numbers.

Allowed types:

```
12
1.3234
0.3423434
23423.12
```

Not allowed types:

```
0012
12.324.12
01.2332
.12
121212.
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Regards!

Comment: I have [updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55256716/5424988) to not match a single or zeroes only including the decimal part `^(?:0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvHuKj/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should do your job.

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMNKMJ/1)**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:` - Beginning of a non-capture group
- `[1-9][0-9]*` - Matches a number not starting with a zero
- `|0` - Or allows matching only a zero to allow numbers like `0.3423434` or `0.1`
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - Optionally allows a decimal part in the number
- `$` - End of string

**Edit: Based on Allan's suggestion to use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`**

In case your input only contains English numbers, or when you only intend to match English numbers, then using `[0-9]` should be preferred for reasons like better performance and wide supported of it across regex engines.

But in case your input contains digits from other languages like Hindi `१` `२` etc. and you want to match any digits, then `\d` should be preferred instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: Nice answer! `^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$` is even better if `\d` is recognized in OP language

Comment: @Allan: Thanks Allan and yes `\d` should be used if one is intending to also match Unicode digits in languages other than English like Hindi `१` or `४`. But instead of one only expects to match only English numbers `0` to `9` then using `[0-9]` give relatively better performance as then it just checks for `0` to `9` English number literals only. So up to OP based upon his input. And thanks again for suggestion, which allowed me to clarify the reason of using `[0-9]`. Let me update that in my post to make it clear.

Comment: The solution is working, however, I would like to make it more strict.
What do I need to add to not allow the '0' value?

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$
```

Beginning of the string, then one or more digits, then (optionally) a dot and one or more digits, then the end of the string.

If you want to cater for the sign, add `[+-]?` after the `^`.

Comment: This regex does match `0012` and `01.2332`... It shouldn't...
You need to add constraint on the first digit encountered

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
^(?:0\.\d*[1-9]\d*|[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvHuKj/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `0\.` Match a single zero followed by a dot
  - `\d*[1-9]\d*` Match 0+ digits, a digit 1-9 and again 0+ digits t prevent only zeroes to match
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 followed by 0+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?)` Optional part to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `)` Close non capturing group